# Getting wrong result when converting percentage field to float

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

I have a query that should display some data based on certain criteria.

When displaying data I have the following condition in my query:

`cast(percentage as float)/100 < 0.50)` which should give me values less then 50%.

However, when executing the query it gives me values like 95, 100...but never gives me less than 0.50, even though I specified condition in a query.

When doing a single select from the table to check what value is there, I'm getting 0.95:

`select cast(percentage as float)/100 from table1 where id ='1111'`

What am I doing wrong? And what is the solution?

---

This is my `where` clause:

```
WHERE msystem = '111'
AND (
     (code = '2222' AND cast(percentage as float)/100 < 0.50)
     OR   (code = '3333')
     )
```

Comment: Can you post more of your query - or at least more of the WHERE clause?  Do you have an `OR` condition?  That can change the results based on operator precedence.

Comment: The query is correct by itself. I will update my post now

Comment: when dealing with Float data type you will get unexpected results in calculations as float is imaginary/Aproximate number and when you doing calculations on imaginary/Aproximate  your results will also be imaginary/Aproximate. To get the exact value use one of the exact data types such as numeric or Decimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code here:

```
(code = '2222' AND cast(percentage as float)/100 < 0.50)
     OR   (code = '3333')
```

That second piece of the **OR (code = '3333')** is allowing for results that are greater than 0.50

The way you have your where clause written right now it shows you any results that have code =  '3333' and only results that have code = '2222' that are less than 0.50

Comment: I need these two conditions to be between certain dates, so that's why I had them between the same brackets.

Comment: Ok, but it still remains that if you write it like that you are allowing values with code = '3333' and no percentage validation which would lead to results outside the bounds of what you originally are looking for. if you want to restrict the values to **only** those that are less than 50% you need to put the restriction on both codes. One thing you can try is using one validation and not the other and see what the results are. That should at least narrow down where you are seeing the issue.